# JSON File / Android - Get the value of string

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have the following JSON file format :

```
{"code":200,
 "status":"OK",
 "data":[
   {"timings":
     {"Fajr":"03:11 (EET)",
      "Sunrise":"04:54 (EET)",
      "Dhuhr":"11:53 (EET)",
      "Asr":"15:29 (EET)",
      "Sunset":"18:52 (EET)",
      "Maghrib":"18:52 (EET)",
      "Isha":"20:23 (EET)",
      "Imsak":"03:01 (EET)",
      "Midnight":"23:53 (EET)"},....
```

I want to get the value of `Asr` (for example) & parse it into string variable, I tried the below but nothing works (Please note: response is successfully retrieved, so no issue with reaching the JSON file, but only to get the value of string).

```
String mfajr = response1.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0)
                        .get("Fajr").toString();

String  mdoher = response1.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0)
                          .getJSONArray("timings")
                          .get(Integer.parseInt("Dhuhr")).toString();
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  A JSON file cannot start with `HTTP/1.1` blah blah, and it cannot end with `},`.  Please show us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt so that we can figure out what you are *actually* doing.

Comment: you are right, i have edited the question above , with part of the raw data , what do you think now ?

Comment: We still need a minimal reproducible example to understand what the type of `response1` is.   And what the exceptions (or whatever) are.

Comment: response1 is JSONObject ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `response1` is a `JSONObject`.

```
String mfajr = response1.getJSONArray("data")
                        .getJSONObject(0)
                        .get("Fajr").toString();
```

That will fail because `getJSONObject(0)` returns an object that has a `"timings"` attribute ... not a `"Fajr"` attribute.

```
String  mdoher = response1.getJSONArray("data")
                          .getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("timings")
                          .get(Integer.parseInt("Dhuhr")).toString();
```

That will fail because the value of `"timings"` attribute is JSON object, not a JSON array.

Also, the value of the `"Dhuhr"` attribute is not an integer, so `parseInt` is not going to work.  If you want the value as an integer, you are going to do some string analysis to convert `"11:53 (EET)"` to an integer.

Basically, you need to make sure that your Java code **precisely** matches the JSON structure.  Close enough is **NOT** good enough.

---

OK .... so you want someone to write your code for you.

Try this:

```
String mfajr = response1.getJSONArray("data")
                        .getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("timings")
                        .getString("Fajr");
```

Now, compare it with the structure of the JSON.

Comment: Great, so in your opinion , what's the code to write to reach Fajr attribute taking into consideration the above JSON structure ?

Comment: I added an image of the JSON file structure in the question header as well, what do you think now ?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  In this case, it adds precisely zero ... because we already have the JSON as text.

Comment: got the below error :

Comment: 2022-06-12 16:07:20.486 13041-13041/com.company.newsalah W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"Fajr":"03:11 (EET)","Sunrise":"04:54 (EET)","Dhuhr":"11:53 (EET)","Asr":"15:29 (EET)","Sunset":"18:52 (EET)","Maghrib":"18:52 (EET)","Isha":"20:23 (EET)","Imsak":"03:01 (EET)","Midnight":"23:53 (EET)"} at timings of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
2022-06-12 16:07:20.486 13041-13041/com.company.newsalah W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:101)

Comment: We still need a minimal reproducible example.  So write one.

Comment: now it works with your query , it was giving an error as another query line was not valid, i know now if something is wrong with small part , it would throw exception for all , and nothing will result up, many thanks , your help was much appreciated